# How to set name of final output .csv file to the name of the folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a working Windows batch script which combines multiple CSV files with same headers into one big CSV file. It is as follows:

```
@echo off

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0

ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set cnt=1

for %%i in (*.csv) do (

  if !cnt!==1 (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  ) else if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
)
```

I want the output file to be the same name as the folder name, instead of `combined.csv`.

For example, if the name of the folder is ABC, then output combined CSV file should be `ABC.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion    

    pushd "%~dp0"

    set "first=1"
    for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do (
        del "%%~nxa.csv" 2>nul 
        (for %%i in (*.csv) do (
            if /i not "%%~nxi"=="%%~nxa.csv" if defined first (
                set "first="
                type "%%~fi"
            ) else (
                (for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%%~fi") do echo(%%j)
            )
        )) > "%%~fa\%%~nxa.csv"
    )
```